# Need help creating nested IF and LEFT formula in a calculated column

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have the following data in a text column called [Workcenter]

```
1 SOCS

CSS

SCXP

SCQA

SCOO

SCPR
```

I need a formula which will create the following results

```
CC

CC

SCX

SCQ

SCO

SCP
```

I'm trying to combine these 2 working formulas

```
=IF([Workcenter]="1 SOCS","CC",IF([Workcenter]="CSS","CC"))

=LEFT([Workcenter],LEN([Workcenter])-1)
```

I tried this formula without success

```
=IF(Workcenter="1 SOCS","CC",IF(Workcenter="CSS","CC"(=LEFT([Workcenter],LEN([Workcenter])-1))))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help Mike! This is what I have working:

=IF(OR([Workcenter]="1 SOCS",[Workcenter]="CSS"),"CC",LEFT([Workcenter],LEN([Workcenter])-1))

Answer (score 0):

Equals ("=") just means a formula follows. You one need one per formula. Try removing the extra equal sign in front of the LEFT.

```
=IF(Workcenter="1 SOCS","CC",IF(Workcenter="CSS","CC", (LEFT([Workcenter],LEN([Workcenter])-1))))
```

A more neatly formatted version:

```
=IF(
    Workcenter="1 SOCS","CC",
    IF(
       Workcenter="CSS","CC",
       LEFT([Workcenter],LEN([Workcenter])-1)
    )
 )
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I also tried, no luck: =IF(Workcenter="1 SOCS","CC",IF(Workcenter="CSS","CC"(LEFT(Workcenter,LEN(Workcenter)-1))))

Comment: What was the error? Would it save the formula, but display the correct results. (I'll go and create a test list...)

Comment: You were missing a comma, just before "(LEFT". I fixed in the answer above.